# Can running gtk app in kde via flatpak cause issues in KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde, gtk, flatpak

I am very new to linux so this is probably a silly question. I am getting used to the various desktop environments, and different frameworks around linux.

I am using KDE (on kubuntu) and installing an application via flatpak. While installing I see the following prompts

```
        ID                                             Branch                 Op            Remote             Download
 1.     org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default            23.08                  i             flathub            < 164.6 MB
 2.     org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default            23.08-extra            i             flathub            < 164.6 MB
 3.     org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264              2.2.0                  i             flathub            < 944.3 kB
 4.     org.gnome.Platform.Locale                      45                     i             flathub            < 369.6 MB (partial)
 5.     org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Breeze                       3.22                   i             flathub            < 192.0 kB
 6.     org.gnome.Platform                             45                     i             flathub            < 375.2 MB
 7.     com.github.d4nj1.tlpui                         stable                 i             flathub            < 807.1 kB

Proceed with these changes to the system installation? [Y/n]:
```

I see gnome mentioned in there. Will installing this package which also installs `org.gnome.Platform` lead to any clashes or issues on my system which uses KDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I see gnome mentioned in there. Will installing this package which also installs org.gnome.Platform lead to any clashes or issues on my system which uses KDE?

Short answer: **No**.

---

Long answer: GTK packages need their own backend to run. If you had installed a .deb GTK package, then APT would install those backends. Most likely, you already have them in your computer if you are using Libreoffice. Similarly, flatpak will install the necessary backends for GTK. They will not interfere with your desktop environments.

It is possible to install the full GNOME and KDE desktop environments simultaneously, and they usually don't clash with each other. Here you are not even installing the full GNOME desktop. You are just installing containerized (Flatpak) libraries to run some GTK apps.